How to break already set function with ontimer in Turtle Graphic
I am creating a snake game with food teleporting around map. I use ontimer with recursion at the end of function to emulate mole staying at a certain position for a time. I also make the mole to move if turtle ate it. But then, mole teleportation is called two time because of the already set function by ontimer.
def mole_teleport(is_loop=True):
        rand_x = random.randint(-250, 250)
        rand_y = random.randint(-250, 250)
        mole.teleport(rand_x, rand_y)
        if is_loop == False:
            return
        else:
            screen.ontimer(mole_teleport, 3000)

tim = Player() #user_turtle
mole = Turtle("circle")

mole_teleport()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(tim.turn_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(tim.turn_right, "Right")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    tim.move()
    if mole.distance(tim) < 20:
        mole_teleport(is_loop=False)

my-ideal-diagram
I tried to block recursion with argument. What I expect is teleportation timer to be refreshed from start after the turtle has eaten the mole and call mole_teleportation()
EDIT: Player() Class
from turtle import Turtle

SPEED = 3

class Player(Turtle):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.penup()
    
    def move(self):
        self.forward(SPEED)
    
    
    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(90)
        
    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(90)


Can you show Player class, and any other missing code like mole.teleport(rand_x, rand_y) so we have a [mcve]?

why do you use ontimer?  You already runs code in while game_is_on: so it will execute mole_teleport again and you may only check time from previous execution and run code only if it passed 3000 ms. And don't run mole_teleport() before loop. OR run first mole_teleport also with mole_teleport(False)

turtle is create on tkinter and normal tkinter has function process_id = after(millisecond, function) similar to ontimer but it gives process_id which you can use to stop timer.

the only idea: don't use ontimer but execute mole_teleport in every loop, and use some variable which time when it should execute - next_execute = next_execute + 3000 and mole_teleport should first compare next_execute >= time.time(). This way when you eat mole then you can set next_execute = time.time() + 3000 and this should move next teleport.

Actually you shouldn't be using while at all. Use ontimer for all game updating.

turtle is created with tkitner which has similar function task_id = root.after(millisecond, function) and it gives taks_id which you can use to delete task, and later you could create new task - so you would have only one timer-loop.
There are even method to access root in turtle but I would do it without ontimer but using time.time() in while-loop to check if mole_time_to_teleport <= time.time() and to teleport mole, and set new time mole_time_to_teleport += 3.
And when snake ate mole then it can simply set mole_time_to_teleport = time.time() to teleport mole at once - and function will also set mole_time_to_teleport += 3.

I tried to recreate Player but it slow, so I also use click on mole to eat it.
from turtle import *
import random
import time

class Player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        
    def move_forward(self):
        self.forward(10)

    def move_backward(self):
        self.backward(10)
        
    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(10)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(10)
        
def mole_teleport():
    global mole_time_to_teleport

    if mole_time_to_teleport <= time.time():
        rand_x = random.randint(-250, 250)
        rand_y = random.randint(-250, 250)
        mole.goto(rand_x, rand_y)
        mole_time_to_teleport += 3  # set next teleport after 3 seconds
        
def eat_mole(x=None, y=None):
    global mole_time_to_teleport
        
    print('eat')
    mole_time_to_teleport = time.time()  # reset to current time 
    #mole_teleport()  # while-loop will run `mole_teleport()`  so I don't need it here

    
tim = Player()     
mole = Turtle("circle")
mole.penup()

mole_time_to_teleport = time.time()  # it will teleport at once, and it will set start position

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(tim.turn_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(tim.turn_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(tim.move_forward, "Up")
screen.onkey(tim.move_backward, "Down")

mole.onclick(eat_mole)  # click on mole to eat it

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    mole_teleport()  # run in every loop 
    
    if mole.distance(tim) < 20:
        eat_mole()
        
    time.sleep(.04)  # slow down code - to use less CPU: 1s/.04 = 25 (Frames Per Second)
    
    screen.update()  # check events and execute `onclick`


EDIT:
The same but with class Mole and list of moles
from turtle import *
import random
import time

# --- classes ---

class Player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()

        screen.onkey(self.turn_left, "Left")
        screen.onkey(self.turn_right, "Right")
        screen.onkey(self.move_forward, "Up")
        screen.onkey(self.move_backward, "Down")
        
    def move_forward(self):
        self.forward(10)

    def move_backward(self):
        self.backward(10)
        
    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(10)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(10)
     
        
class Mole(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, shape, color="black"):
        super().__init__(shape)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.time_to_teleport = time.time()
        
        self.onclick(self.eat)  

    def check_teleport(self):
        if self.time_to_teleport <= time.time():
            rand_x = random.randint(-250, 250)
            rand_y = random.randint(-250, 250)
            #self.speed(0)
            self.goto(rand_x, rand_y)
            #self.speed(6)
            self.time_to_teleport += 3  # set next teleport after 3 seconds
            
    def eat(self, x=None, y=None):
        print('eat')
        self.time_to_teleport = time.time()
        
# --- functions ---
    
# --- main ---

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
    
tim = Player(screen)     

moles = [
    Mole("circle", "red"),
    Mole("square", "green"),
    Mole("triangle", "blue"),
]    

screen.listen()

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    for mole in moles:
        mole.check_teleport()  # run in every loop 

    for mole in moles:
        if mole.distance(tim) < 20:
            mole.eat()
        
    time.sleep(.04)  # slow down code - to use less CPU: 1s/.04 = 25 (Frames Per Second)
    
    screen.update()  # check events and execute `onclick`

